# I am trying to make undo/redo function to a textbox using stack but it only undo one character at a time I want to undo a string

Tags: c#, stack

I am trying to make an undo/redo feature on a textbox in Winforms, I found a code in here that works but it only undo one character at a time. I was hoping to undo a whole string, can someone help me or give me an idea how? I'm new at data structure and don't really know how to start.

Here's the code:

```
        Stack<Func<object>> undoStack = new Stack<Func<object>>();
        Stack<Func<object>> redoStack = new Stack<Func<object>>();

        public LowQuantityProd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.KeyDown += TextBox1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) { }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                if (undoStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    StackPush(sender, redoStack);
                    undoStack.Pop()();
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.R && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                if (redoStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    StackPush(sender, undoStack);
                    redoStack.Pop()();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                redoStack.Clear();
                StackPush(sender, undoStack);
            }
        }

        private void StackPush(object sender, Stack<Func<object>> stack)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            var tBT = textBox.Text(textBox.Text, textBox.SelectionStart);
            stack.Push(tBT);
        }
}

public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Func<TextBox> Text(this TextBox textBox, string text, int sel)
        {
            return () =>
            {
                textBox.Text = text;
                textBox.SelectionStart = sel;
                return textBox;
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a matter of what you (i.e. your algorithm) consider "one thing". If that is "change of one character" then it's that. If you want "a string" you need a way to save the "thing" to be that string. Makes sense?

Comment: For example: When I am typing, change happens frequently. When I stop typing, that could trigger a threshold or if I click the mouse ... then that's the "End Marker" and the string I typed is "the thing".

Comment: As long as neither Undo nor Redo is executed, you can append any additional typed characters to an existing "undo unit".

Comment: i would think you would push on to the stack after a focus change or ENTER keydown